# virt-manager GUI is not opening on target machine

Tags: systemd, filesystems, virtual-machine, libvirt, administration

I am able to connect virt-manager to a standalone production server from my laptop. When I ssh using virt-manager it's not showing the production server, just the other two VMs I have on the production server.

I was expecting the GUI window to open so I could control the machine, but it didn't. Do you have any ideas?

[image]

Comment: Please clarify this question. Is the production server a VM? Then what does it mean to “connect to” it? Why is this question tagged [tag:virtualbox]? Is the production server a VirtualBox VM?

Comment: updated hope this helps